# Table of db is empty when imported XML file

Tags: c#, mysql, xml, dataset

I need to import this XML file created with a dataset in C# into a MySQL table.

[image]

I have tried the [LOAD XML](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html) syntax method:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 
'D:\\Area Open\\text.xml' INTO TABLE `tbl_open`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '</Table>' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

I don't have error on the import procedure but the `tbl_open` is empty.

```
Affected rows: 0
Time: 892.723ms
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax **LOAD XML** in your case is:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 
'D:\\Area Open\\text.xml' INTO TABLE `tbl_open`
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Table>';
```

Hope this helps!

Happy coding !